# jQuery UI: How to add ID to combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, combobox

I have a website with three comboboxes. I use the comobox widget for jQuery UI. I would like to be able to individually style each combox via addressing an id instead of using the nth-type selector. How can I add an id when a combobox gets initialized?

My JS:

```
$('#my-select-1').combobox();
$('#my-select-2').combobox();
$('#my-select-3').combobox();
```

Applying the comobox widget, results in the following markup:

```
<select id="my-select-1" style="display:none;">
<span class="custom-combobox">...</span>
<select id="my-select-2" style="display:none;">
<span class="custom-combobox">...</span>
<select id="my-select-3" style="display:none;">
<span class="custom-combobox">...</span>
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/3xkaj0ah/1/

My goal is that I can give each `<span class="custom-combobox">` element an id.

Comment: `$('.custom-combobox').each(function(index){ this.id='span-'+index; });`

Comment: I am looking for a more individual way of doing this. Can't I somehow add an ID when I initialize the combobox with `$('#my-select-1').combobox()`? Maybe I can add a method in the widget code, something like "setId" and pass the ID as a parameter?

Comment: Ooh.. Then `$('#my-select-3').combobox().next('span').attr('id','YOUR_ID');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.

```
$('#my-select-1').combobox();
$('#my-select-1').next('.custom-combobox').attr('id','aa');
$('#my-select-2').combobox();
$('#my-select-2').next('.custom-combobox').attr('id','bb');
$('#my-select-3').combobox();
$('#my-select-3').next('.custom-combobox').attr('id','cc');
```